# Populate PHP Array with Particular Day of Week For a Date Range (using Laravel)

Tags: php, arrays, date, reference

I'm trying to populate an array with every particular weekday, say Sunday, between a start date and an end date.

The best I could think of is as below. (The dates are actually Carbon dates.)

This seems to work, except that I have noticed when I `dd()` the result, all array elements are assigned the final value of `$d` (= `$endDate_Planned`). If I `info()` log these I see that its working at the point in time each is pushed into the array, but obviously the values are some sort of reference that gets updated every time `$d` updates/increments.

Is there a way to avoid that?

```
for( $d = $startDate_Planned; $d <= $endDate_Planned; $d->addDays(7) ) {
    info($d);
    $dateArray_Planned[] = $d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's ugly. The reason is that `$d` is an object. Every element of `$dateArray_Planned` is a reference to the same object.

I wouldn't use a `for`, but if I had, I'd just try `copy()`ing the object on each iteration.

```
$dateArray_Planned[]=$d->copy();
```

Comment: Ok cheers. Is there a better way to do this? I just want to get an array with every Sunday from A to B.

Comment: Do you *really* have to use Carbon?

Comment: Not really. You've called my existing code ugly and then used italics so I'm guessing you have a very concise and efficient way of doing this and I'm very much looking forward to learning from someone like you who this must be much easier for. Thank you in advance.

Comment: (That's not meant to come across anything but literally.)

Comment: Sorry I didn't want to hurt you. It was ugly in the sense that it didn't work, right? and it isn't the cleanest code with a `for` used in that way. The *really* meaning that if you have the actual requirement to use it or it's just something you like/found. If you don't have a requirement to use it, you could do it much more efficiently (no objects) and cleanly with just epoch time values. But if you prefer, or *have to* use Carbon, duplicating/creating a new instance of it would be the way to go. My apologies, again.

Comment: No need for apologies, I think my post reads different to how I intended. I appreciate the opportunity to learn from you. I don't have to use Carbon at all, and the I agree its really cumbersome looking code (I'm a novice) so please do suggest a better way to do this if you will. All I want is an array of Sundays between two dates (that I'm happy to pass in as yyyy-mm-dd). For each element of the array I'll be doing something.